# Force stylesheet_link_tag to locate hashed asset in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

We're coming off of using the asset_sync gem for managing our assets. I'm trying to setup the Asset Pipeline using these settings.

**development.rb**

```
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = false
```

**application.rb**

```
  config.assets.enabled = true
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.version = '1.1'
```

I'm precompiling in Development and the assets are going into the public directory (hashed asset for each file). When using the stylesheet_link_tag, it works perfectly if I refer to the hashed asset directly:

```
stylesheet_link_tag("/assets/branding/visit/skin-295511b052d49d541763f276ddcf4efc.css")
```

But I need to be able to just call skin.css and be served the correct hashed skin.css file. I currently get a 404 with this:

```
stylesheet_link_tag("/assets/branding/visit/skin.css")
```

Is there a setting I'm missing to point to the hashed asset? Thanks for any advice.

**Tech Specs**

Ruby: 2.3.1

Rails: 4.2.7.1